# Magento 2 call the product photos in product description

Tags: magento2, product-images

In Magento 2 product details page wants to show the product photos in the description tab.

the phtml temp:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php if($_product->getMgsDetailTemplate() == ""): ?>
    <?php $templateLayout = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/product_ct_template'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php $templateLayout = $_product->getMgsDetailTemplate(); ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php $helper = $this->helper('MGS\Protabs\Helper\Data') ?>
<?php $tabCollection = $helper->getTabsCollection() ?>
<?php if(count($tabCollection)): ?>
    <?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/type')): ?>
        <div class="product-detail-infomation margin-top65">
    <?php endif ?>
    <div class="product info detailed <?php if(!$helper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/type') && !$helper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/position')): ?>after-content<?php endif ?>">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php if($templateLayout!=5): ?>
            <div class="product-data-items-menu">
                <?php foreach($tabCollection as $_tab): ?>
                    <?php if(($_tab->getTabType() == 'attribute') || ($_tab->getTabType() == 'static')): ?>
                        <?php if(trim($_tab->getValue()) !=''): ?>
                            <?php if($_tab->getTabType() == 'attribute'): ?>
                                <?php 
                                    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description')
                                    ->setAtCall($helper->convertAttributeToCallName($_tab->getValue()))
                                    ->setAtCode($_tab->getValue())
                                    ->setCssClass('description')
                                    ->setAtLabel('none')
                                    ->setAtType($helper->getAttributeType($_tab->getValue()))
                                    ->setTitle($_tab->getTitle())
                                    ->setTemplate('MGS_Protabs::product/view/attribute.phtml')
                                    ->toHtml() 
                                ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_tab->getValue())->toHtml() ?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php 
                                if (!trim($html)) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $alias = $_tab->getTabType().$_tab->getValue();
                                $label = $_tab->getTitle();
                            ?>

                            <div class="data item title"
                                 aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php echo $alias;?>-title"
                                 data-role="collapsible" data-itemactive=".accordion-<?php echo $alias;?>" id="tab-label-<?php echo $alias;?>">
                                <a class="data switch"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   data-toggle="switch"
                                   href="#<?php echo $alias; ?>"
                                   id="tab-label-<?php echo $alias;?>-title">
                                    <?php echo $label; ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php 
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($_tab->getTabType());
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($_tab->getTabType());

                            $label = $_tab->getTitle();


                            if($alias == 'reviews'){
                                $oldLabel = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                                if(is_object($oldLabel)){
                                    $labelObject = (array)$oldLabel;
                                    $countArray = end($labelObject);
                                    if(isset($countArray[0])){
                                        $label = $label.' '.$countArray[0].'';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="data item title"
                             aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                             data-role="collapsible" data-itemactive=".accordion-<?php echo $alias;?>" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                            <a class="data switch"
                               tabindex="-1"
                               data-toggle="switch"
                               href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                               id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product-data-items-content">
                <?php $dn = 0; $dx=0; foreach($tabCollection as $_tab): ?>
                    <?php if(($_tab->getTabType() == 'attribute') || ($_tab->getTabType() == 'static')): $dn++; ?>
                        <?php if(trim($_tab->getValue()) !=''):?>
                            <?php if($_tab->getTabType() == 'attribute'): ?>
                                <?php 
                                    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description')
                                    ->setAtCall($helper->convertAttributeToCallName($_tab->getValue()))
                                    ->setAtCode($_tab->getValue())
                                    ->setCssClass('description')
                                    ->setAtLabel('none')
                                    ->setAtType($helper->getAttributeType($_tab->getValue()))
                                    ->setTitle($_tab->getTitle())
                                    ->setTemplate('MGS_Protabs::product/view/attribute.phtml')
                                    ->toHtml() 
                                ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_tab->getValue())->toHtml() ?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php 
                                if (!trim($html)) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $alias = $_tab->getTabType().$_tab->getValue();
                                $label = $_tab->getTitle();
                            ?>
                            <div class="title-accordion<?php if($dn == 1): ?> active <?php endif; ?> accordion-<?php echo $alias;?>" data-toggle="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?></div>
                            <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php else: $dx++;?>
                        <?php 
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($_tab->getTabType());
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($_tab->getTabType());

                            $label = $_tab->getTitle();


                            if($alias == 'reviews'){
                                $oldLabel = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                                if(is_object($oldLabel)){
                                    $labelObject = (array)$oldLabel;
                                    $countArray = end($labelObject);
                                    if(isset($countArray[0])){
                                        $label = $label.' '.$countArray[0].'';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="title-accordion<?php if($dx == 1): ?> active <?php endif ?> accordion-<?php echo $alias;?>" data-toggle="#<?php echo $alias; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></div>
                        <div class="data item content" id="<?php echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content"><?php echo $html; ?></div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        <?php else:?>
            <div class="product-data-items-content">
                <?php $dn = 0; foreach($tabCollection as $_tab): $dn++; ?>
                    <?php if(($_tab->getTabType() == 'attribute') || ($_tab->getTabType() == 'static')): ?>
                        <?php if(trim($_tab->getValue()) !=''): ?>
                            <?php if($_tab->getTabType() == 'attribute'): ?>
                                <?php 
                                    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description')
                                    ->setAtCall($helper->convertAttributeToCallName($_tab->getValue()))
                                    ->setAtCode($_tab->getValue())
                                    ->setCssClass('description')
                                    ->setAtLabel('none')
                                    ->setAtType($helper->getAttributeType($_tab->getValue()))
                                    ->setTitle($_tab->getTitle())
                                    ->setTemplate('MGS_Protabs::product/view/attribute.phtml')
                                    ->toHtml() 
                                ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_tab->getValue())->toHtml() ?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php 
                                if (!trim($html)) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $alias = $_tab->getTabType().$_tab->getValue();
                                $label = $_tab->getTitle();
                            ?>
                            <div class="content-heading"><h3 class="title text-uppercase"><?php echo $label; ?></h3></div>
                            <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php 
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($_tab->getTabType());
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($_tab->getTabType());

                            $label = $_tab->getTitle();


                            if($alias == 'reviews'){
                                $oldLabel = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                                if(is_object($oldLabel)){
                                    $labelObject = (array)$oldLabel;
                                    $countArray = end($labelObject);
                                    if(isset($countArray[0])){
                                        $label = $label.' '.$countArray[0].'';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="content-heading"><h3 class="title text-uppercase"><?php echo $label; ?></h3></div>
                        <div class="data item content" id="<?php echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content"><?php echo $html; ?></div>
                        <?php if($alias=="reviews"):?>
                            <div class="data item title active hidden" aria-labeledby="tab-label-reviews-title" data-role="collapsible" data-itemactive=".accordion-reviews" id="tab-label-reviews" role="tab" data-collapsible="true" aria-controls="reviews" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
                                <a class="data switch" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="switch" href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                require([
                                    'jquery'
                                ], function ($) {
                                     $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('.data.switch').click();
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if($templateLayout!=5): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                'jquery'
            ], function ($) {
                $('.title-accordion').click(function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass('accordion-reviews')){
                        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                            var itemShow = $(this).data('toggle');
                            $(itemShow).slideUp();
                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                        }else{
                            $('.product-data-items-content .title-accordion.active').removeClass('active');
                            $(".product-data-items-content .data.item.content").slideUp();
                            $('#tab-label-reviews a').click();
                            $(this).addClass('active');
                        }
                    }else{
                        var itemShow = $(this).data('toggle');
                        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                            $(itemShow).slideUp();
                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                        }else {
                            $('.product-data-items-content .title-accordion.active').removeClass('active');
                            $(".product-data-items-content .data.item.content").slideUp();
                            $(itemShow).slideDown();
                            $(this).addClass('active');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/type')): ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: i'm using custom theme

Comment: please give the screenshot, also share phtml file code from where the description is showing

Comment: i've added the phtml code